# How to delete Google products shortcuts?

Tags: google-chrome

I use Google Chrome browser. At the New Tab page, there is an App Launcher icon with shortcuts to Google Products, see

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1714464?p=google_bar&rd=1

It is possible to add more shortcuts or change the order of existing shortcuts there. But how can I delete some of those shortcuts?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to 'delete' the shortcuts in the app launcher. That's controlled by Google.

You can however change the preview of shortcuts you see. Install the [App Launcher Customizer for Google](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/app-launcher-customizer-f/ponjkmladgjfjgllmhnkhgbgocdigcjm) extension and configure your shortcuts.

Once installed:

- Reload the page of any Google product you're using (Gmail, Drive, etc.), *or navigate to a popular Google product of your choice*.
- Click the grid (app launcher icon) on the top right and then click `Configure`.

*Before install*

[image: Before]

*After install*

[image: After]

- On the configure page, you can change the order of existing shortcuts and even add links to other websites.

[image: Configure]